# Indication of popular links

Tags: feature-request

I have a simple feature request (suggestion.)  Include a graphic indicator next to provided links that have hit certain milestones on views.

My suggestion is aimed to improve the following situation:

*BlackVegetable is researching a number of topics that have a large number of questions/answers associated with them.  He sees many posts containing links to other websites but does not feel he has the time to investigate every link, even on highly voted answers.  He does not know which links point to valued resources, and cannot feasibly view them all.*

*If he were to have an indicator of which links have 100, 500, or 2000 views with a different colored indicator next to the link, perhaps he would instead pursue visiting the very well-visited (and reputable?) links and ignore the others if he is short on time.*

Comment: Links in a question / answer that point to external web sites? I highly doubt that SO maintains click views on external pointing links, never mind constantly validate that those links are still valid (since if they are no longer valid, what value are the numbers). If BlackVegetable is short on time then perhaps he should focus on questions/answers that aren't just a collection of links? And do you think click/view count is something that really separates  worthwhile resources from non-worthwhile resources? Yeah this works great for up-votes/accepts on questions/answers.

Comment: Hmm, true.  I thought there were badges that *did* track this, though.

Comment: The badges are for posts that have collected views (so they're all part of the site) or for sharing links to questions/answers on external sites/twitter etc. So I guess that they could show view counts for posts within the network, but again why is that valuable? If someone posts a question link on reddit, does 35,000 views mean it is a better resource than another one that wasn't posted on reddit? If you are talking about a list of questions in a search result, prioritizing by votes will give a much better idea about quality than views IMHO.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right.  Sometimes "rubber duck debugging" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) works for questions on Stack Overflow (or Meta in this case.)  Should this question be closed, or would you like to phrase your comment(s) in the form of an answer?

Comment: Whoops, beat you to it.

Comment: Sounds like something  Google does much better. Why not ask them for poplar links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how this helps. I would rather see a post with 10 views and 10 up-votes than a post with 50,000 views and 5 down-votes. Remember that people can be lured into visiting a post through various means, from legit to downright malicious. Landing on a page doesn't mean that I derived any value from doing so, nor that <strike>you</strike> your friend BlackVegetable will.

(Just like the rest of the Internet, good SEO does not necessarily go hand-in-hand with good content.)

Comment: Though I'd definitely be curious to see *why* a post got 50,000 views and 5 downvotes...

Comment: @Mystical because any idiot can post a link to a bad SO question, with the link text, "Hey check out my t*ts for $1" to Craigslist...

Comment: $1 is too much... If it was free I'd understand. :)

Comment: For posterity: _[`@Mystical you haven't seen my t*ts :-) – Aaron Bertrand 37 secs ago`](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4583984#4583984)_

Comment: @sehe yeah I removed it since I figured it would get flagged as offensive

Comment: This is meta, you can't offend anyone. XD

Comment: Not with your careful censorship it's not! (I fail at sarcasm today, so I'll just say that saying "t*ts" is dumb.)

Comment: There are nothing wrong with tots.